# Jinput Poll Data Never Changes

Tags: java, input, controller, robotics, jinput

I am attempting to create a simple test program to get familiar with the JInput Library for another project. I have tested my controller with the all of the provided test classes and it works as expected. However, when I attempt to poll the controller, all values remain unchanged regardless of my input. Here is the code I am working with:

`public class ControllerTest {`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //System.out.println("Hello World");

    Controller[] ca = ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment().getControllers();
    Controller gamepad = null;
    Component[] components = null;
    EventQueue eventQueue;
    // Run through the list of available input devices and get the gamepad
    for(int i = 0; i < ca.length; i ++){
        if(ca[i].getType().equals(Controller.Type.GAMEPAD)){
            gamepad = ca[i];
        }
    }
    // Print the name of the controller and its type
    if(gamepad != null){
        System.out.println(gamepad.getName() + ": " + gamepad.getType());
        components = gamepad.getComponents();
        System.out.println("\tComponents:");
        for(int i = 0; i < components.length; i ++){
            System.out.println("\t\tComponent #" + i + ": " + components[i].getName() + "\n\t\t\tIs Relative: "
                    + components[i].isRelative());
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No gamepad connected");
    }

    while (true){
        // If we have no gamepad connected, exit
        if(gamepad == null){
            System.out.println("No Gamepad detected, exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // Poll controller
        gamepad.poll();
        Component[] comp = gamepad.getComponents();

        for(int i = 0; i < comp.length; i ++){
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append(comp[i].getName());
            buffer.append(", Value: " + comp[i].getPollData());
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(20);  // Sleep before polling again
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have been trying to find an answer online, but this library is not very well documented and seems to usually be wrapped in other libraries specific for making games. (The aforementioned project is robotic in nature)

Answer (score 0):

I was consistently getting only zero values using JInput for mouse X and y locations when building a console application like you have shown above.  I believe it may be necessary to create a window-focused application of some kind for JInput to work.  See here a code example solution and similar issue described.
[code solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091388/jinput-get-mouse-location/50611749#50611749)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use an EventQueue

```
player.poll();
        EventQueue queue = player.getEventQueue();
        Event event = new Event();
        while (queue.getNextEvent(event)) {
            Component comp = event.getComponent();
            if (comp.getIdentifier() == Component.Identifier.Button._6){
                if (comp.getPollData() == 1){
                    example
                }
```

Comment: So I tried implementing this version of polling the controller but unfortunately now it prints nothing at all. There seems to be a weird disconnect somewhere in the code since the test classes provided with the library do work with my controller.